# Ignore a default library in MingW?

Tags: mingw, default, linker-errors

I know there is -nodefaultlibs, but I just want to ignore 1.  I think you can do this in VS, but I haven't been able to find a way to do it in gcc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If memory serves me right, you may need to use -nodefaultlibs and then include the libs you do need. I'm not sure you can just ignore one library.